# Why foreign key doesn't update?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I insert data in the column `TEMP1.aa` (primary key in temp1), but it doesn't import into the `TEMP2.cc` column (foreign key in TEMP2).

Why?

I thought if insert data in primary key it automatic insert into foreign key! If this true that if we insert in a primary key, foreign key must be updated?

Comment: I don't think you understand foreign keys at all.

Comment: Unless you have some sort of trigger setup, just because something is a foreign key doesn't mean it will automatically update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A foreign key does not update child references, it only ensures that the value stored in the column already exists in the parent table.

But MySQL supports cascading an update, by adding the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to the foreign key constraint in the TEMP1 table.  Otherwise, you need to consider using a trigger for more elaborate rules/requirements.

Reference:

- [MySQL - Foreign Key Constraints documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)
- [MySQL - Triggers documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

Comment: tangential to question. UPDATE CASCADE has nothing to do with the INSERT op in the question

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: If inserting (meaning, adding new parent table data), there'd be no child references to correct.  Check the edit history for the OPs questions, you'll find that English is not their native language.

Answer (score 1):

No, foreign keys do not work like that.

Foreign keys are used on to link two tables together via the key. On one table, you have the `PRIMARY KEY` and all the attributes relative to that entity.

On the other table, you have the `FOREIGN KEY` which tells the database *"hey you, the user, you can only insert a value here if it also exists as a `PRIMARY KEY` in my reference table"*.

It is still up to you, the user, to choose if you want to `INSERT` a row in your foreign table or not.

---

If you need the foreign table to always have a row referencing to its correspondant in the primary table, chances are that you could convert that table to additional columns as they are attributes to the same entity. *There are exceptions to this* but going into detail will just add to your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these tables

```
Fruits
ID   Name
1    Apple
2    Orange
3    Grapes

Sales
ID   Fruit   Amount
1    1       2.45
2    3       1.23
3    1       2.23
4    2       6.22
```

The foreign key on `Sales(Fruit) to Fruits(ID)` ensures that each Fruit value in Sales must match an ID from Fruits.  Not, on to your question

> I insert data in the column aa (primary key in temp1), but it doesn't import into the TMP2.cc column (foreign key in temp2).

So we insert a record in to Fruits (ID: 4, Name: Pear).  You want to import it into Sales? How?

Read up on some basics about Foreign Keys

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key
- http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-foreign-key.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html