# Laravel 5.2 Update with foreign key

Tags: laravel, sql-update, laravel-5

hello i've been working on a laravel project lately, and i've wanted to be able to update my records that have foreign keys in them. i've succesfully been able to update records in tables that dont have a foreign key but for some reason my table with a foreign key doesn't want to update. when i var_dump($voorraad) i get the new value on my screen but it doesn't update into the database. I have the same code for my Product table and Location table and there it works completely fine.

My Controller:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //voorraad = stock in dutch
    //Product_id = foreign key from the table products
    //locatie_Id = foreign key from the tabe locations
    //aantal = ammount of a certain product

    $voorraad = Voorraad::FindOrFail($id);


    $voorraad->fill($request->only('aantal', 'Product_id', 'locatie_Id'));

    $voorraad->save();

    return redirect(route('voorraad.index'));

}
```

My voorraad model

```
   class Voorraad extends Model
{
    //aantal is the ammount 


protected $fillable = ['aantal', 'Product_id', 'locatie_Id'];
protected $table = 'voorraad';

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'Product_id');
}

public function locaties()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Locatie', 'locatie_Id');
}
```

My Product Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
//inkoopprijs = sell price
//verkoop prijs = buy price
//naam = product name


protected $fillable = ['naam', 'inkoopprijs', 'verkoopprijs','created_at', 'updated_at'];

protected $table = 'product';
```

}

My Location Model:

```
class Locatie extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['naam'];

protected $table = 'locatie';    
}
```

My edit form:

```
    {!! Form::model($voorraad,['action' => ['VoorraadsController@update', $voorraad->Id], 'method' => 'PATCH'])!!}

{!! Form::label('aantal', 'aantal:') !!}
{!! Form::text('aantal')!!}<br>

{!! Form::label('Product_id', 'product:') !!} 
{!! Form::select('Product_id', $products)!!}<br>

{!! Form::label('locatie_Id', 'locatie:') !!} 
{!! Form::select('locatie_Id', $locaties)!!} <br>

{!! Form::submit('edit') !!}
```

Gyazo of Var_dump($voorraad): https://gyazo.com/109d54e2bb7a91bbb8b047611e66dbe0

gyazo of var_dump($request):https://gyazo.com/8437ee90881ba38a039b5b583f8296a5

If there is any information missing just let me know and i'll add it

Comment: What kind of relations do you use? Depending on the type of the relation, it is good practice to use functions such as save(), attach(), sync() or associate(). [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models).

Comment: the relastion between the tables is BelongsTo

Comment: could you please post your models relationships?

Comment: i've edited the post and included the models with there relationships

Comment: Foreign Key value works as an identifier of a row (usually contains PRIMARY KEY) of another table. But you want to update your foreign fields with product amount. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5292099/2429040. Hope you will have a clear understanding :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the model and associate it with the Product and Location it belongs to like this:

```
$voorraad = Voorraad::findOrFail($id); 
$product = Product::findOrFail($request->input('Product_id'));
$location = Location::findOrFail($request->input('locatie_Id'));

$voorraad->aantal = $request->input('aantal');
$voorraad->save();

$product->voorraad()->associate($voorraad);
$location->voorraad()->associate($voorraad);
```

Of course you have to use the proper names for your models.

Comment: when i use this code with the proper models i get a error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::voorraad()

Comment: Did you define the relations on you models? You need a voorraad() or voorraden() function in both your Product and Location model.

Comment: what eloquent relation do i need to put in the Product and location model?